# Values not added to thye new column of dataset

Tags: c#, datatable

I added a column to my `datatable` and add values to the column based on a condition but the value is not added to the `datatable`*(even though there should be values)*

This is part of the code I used

```
conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;
                                Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\LR Product Database 2000.mdb"));
        conn.Open();

        Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CODE, TITLE FROM tblProducts";

        OleDbDataReader dbread = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dbread.Read())
        {
            productCode = (string)dbread["CODE"];
            productTitle = (string)dbread["TITLE"];
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(productCode + " ");
            items.Add(productCode, productTitle);
        }

        sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LRVWebsite"].ToString());
        sqlCon.Open();
        dsSql = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter dba = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT C.CustomerFirstName,C.CustomerLastName, C.CustomerCompany,C.CustomerPosition,C.CustomerCountry,C.CustomerProvince,C.CustomerContact,CP.ActionDate,CP.ProductCode,CP.CustomerEmail FROM tblCustomers C INNER JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP ON C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail ORDER BY ActionDate DESC", connString);
        dba.Fill(dsSql,"Products");
        DataTable dt = dsSql.Tables["Products"];
        dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if(items.ContainsKey(dr["ProductCode"].ToString()))
            {

                dr["Title"] = items[dr["ProductCode"].ToString()];

            }
        }
```

How can I add the values to the new column based on the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the first part (+ use `using`) and use `Enumerable.Join`:

```
DataTable tblAccess = new DataTable();
using(var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\LR Product Database 2000.mdb"))
using(var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT CODE, TITLE FROM tblProducts", con))
{ 
    da.Fill(tblAccess);
}

DataTable tblSqlServer = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LRVWebsite"].ToString()))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT C.CustomerFirstName,C.CustomerLastName, C.CustomerCompany,C.CustomerPosition,C.CustomerCountry,C.CustomerProvince,C.CustomerContact,CP.ActionDate,CP.ProductCode,CP.CustomerEmail FROM tblCustomers C INNER JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP ON C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail ORDER BY ActionDate DESC", con))
{ 
    da.Fill(tblSqlServer);
}
```

Now it's easy to join both tables with `Linq-To-DataSet` and get the new title for your sql-server row:

```
var both = from rowSql in tblSqlServer.AsEnumerable()
           join rowAcc in tblAccess.AsEnumerable()
           on rowSql.Field<string>("ProductCode") equals rowAcc.Field<string>("ProductCode")
           select new { rowSql = rowSql, newTitle = rowAcc.Field<string>("Title") };

foreach (var x in both)
{
    x.rowSql.SetField("Title", x.newTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, create an empty column in the select `'' AS Title` and then fill it.  You could also put your logic in the sql (join to an items table.):

```
    SqlDataAdapter dba = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT '' as Title, C.CustomerFirstName,C.CustomerLastName, C.CustomerCompany,C.CustomerPosition,C.CustomerCountry,C.CustomerProvince,C.CustomerContact,CP.ActionDate,CP.ProductCode,CP.CustomerEmail FROM tblCustomers C INNER JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP ON C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail ORDER BY ActionDate DESC", connString);
    dba.Fill(dsSql,"Products");
    DataTable dt = dsSql.Tables["Products"];

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if(items.ContainsKey(dr["ProductCode"].ToString()))
        {

            dr["Title"] = items[dr["ProductCode"].ToString()];

        }
    }
```